# How do I tell all my AWS EC2 instances to pull from git / codecommit?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I am using AWS CodeCommit which seems to be like a stripped down version of git.

If all these EC2 instances have the same role tag how do I accomplish this?

I don't want to do anything fancy, all I want is to be specify a tag, click a button and all those EC2 instances with that tag pull for CodeCommit. I want to do this from my local machine.

I know I need to put the SSH keys to access CodeCommit in each of my EC2 servers and install git on each of them (I will bake this into an AMI). I'm just not sure how to "trigger" each of the EC2 machines to do a git pull? Is there an AWS command?

I am not a dev ops guy and only know basic linux and php.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For EC2 instances that are launched with an IAM role, you don't even have to bake in SSH keys.  Git can get CodeCommit credentials from the EC2 instance metadata.  Bake a Linux-based AMI with the latest AWS CLI package and the following lines in ~/.gitconfig:

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws --profile default codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

Launch the instance with an IAM role attached, and then you can clone your CodeCommit repo without any more setup.

You might want to look into [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) and [Capify-EC2](https://github.com/forward3d/cap-ec2) if you want to run git commands across a fleet of EC2 instances based on tags.

Updated:
If you're open to using AWS OpsWorks to deploy from CodeCommit, there's a [recent blog article](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2FNRSKWQ3BQ9B/Integrating-AWS-OpsWorks-and-AWS-CodeCommit) about how to do that.  You can also use OpsWorks to [run arbitrary commands](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/TxKJT2OU7YZCXI/Using-Capistrano-to-run-arbitrary-commands-on-AWS-OpsWorks-instances) across instances with Capistrano.

Comment: I wish I had this answer back when I asked the question. In the end I used Fabric to run git clone commands across my EC2 fleet.

Comment: If anyone is trying this and having trouble with "profile default not found", try `''` to specify a blank profile. Your profile may/should be stored in an environment variable `$AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @RobbieAverill You can just leave out the `--profile default` bit entirely (and as you are saying, setting it to default doesn't work if you have no default profile)

Answer (score 4):

The closest you'll get to it with AWS managed services is ***CodeDeploy***. With it, you can orchestrate deployment in *EC2* instances via command line or web console. But *CodeDeploy* just pulls artifacts from *S3* or *GitHub*, so far. By now, ***CodeCommit*** seems to be completely isolated from other related Amazon services, like ***CodePipeline*** and ***CodeDeploy***, so it doesn't seem to be a good choice. But, off course, Amazon roadmap is to integrate all them (not doing this would be pointless). So, righ now, you would be better using *GitHub* than *CodeCommit*.

But, considering you are not using *GitHub*, then you need a *CI* (continuous integration) solution between you repository and *CodeDeploy*, pulling code from the source, possibly building or running tests, pushing it to *S3* and telling *CodeDeploy* about it. There's [*CodeShip*](https://codeship.com/), for example, which can do that, and integrates with a lot of external services. Or you could even have your own *CI* server, like *[Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)*, doing that "glue" role for you. (Jenkins will probably be the most flexible one because it's open-source and may have plugins for everything.)

So, breaking down a little bit, you workflow would be something like that:

- push code to your repository;
- whenever there's an event (a commit on some branch, or a new tag, it should be configurable), your *CI* pulls it, run whatever you want or need (builds, tests, packs it), and pushes it to *S3* (as a tarball file, usually);
- depending on how you have set things, your *CI* tells *Code Deploy* to deploy it on your *EC2* instances right away, or it just tells it there's a new version available, and lets you to trigger the deploy, manually, via CLI on web console, whenever you want.

(Actually, *CodeDeploy* doesn't push code to *EC2* instances. Instead, each *EC2* instance must run an agent which pools regularly *CodeDeploy* server in order to know if there's something new to be applied locally. Anyway, *CodeDeploy* coordinates and get feedback from the agents, so it just works as if it were 100% active on *CodeDeploy* side and 100% passive on the instances side.)

The most "clean" AWS solution would be ***CodeCommit*** -> **CodePipeline** -> ***CodeDeploy***, or just ***CodeCommit*** -> ***CodeDeploy***, but those services are not completely integrated by now.

In your case, the simplest and viable solution right now would be *Github* -> *CodeDeploy*. Anything different from that will demand some intermediate steps on the way, like the examples I provided (*CodeShip*, *Jenkins*, etc).